# Conditional div float right (if there is enough space for it after text) with CSS only

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have a div with a lot of text and link "read more" after the text. I want the "Read more" to float on the right after the text. But only if there is enough space for it. If there isn't I want the "Read more" to be just displayed after the text in next line. I was trying to accomplished that using flex, but unfortunately it got me nowhere because the text was recognized as a whole block.

I've prepared code sandbox where you can see my problem visualized.

[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-rosalind-2ldzl)

```
.read-more {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: blueviolet;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  float: right; // I would like to have this line conditional somehow. Probably using float is not a way to go at all
}
```

Is it possible to get something like that with CSS only?

Comment: No...I don't believe there is - the best you can hope for is https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NQdzKa

Answer (score 0):

You could create the element in a DOM node (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) and add logic to check the screen size with screen.width, then create it based on if it fits.

Answer (score -1):

commented `float: right`. is this what you wanted??

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.entry {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid palevioletred 3px;
  width: 400px;
}

.read-more {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: blueviolet;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* float: right; */
}

.no-float {
  float: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="entry">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione dolorem eos et totam doloribus ipsa illo porro unde, asperiores consequatur tempore dolor, veritatis quod corporis enim nesciunt. Impedit error atque veniam tempore ea facilis natus voluptatibus.
      Illo vitae consequatur explicabo...
      <div class="read-more">
        Read more
      </div>
    </div>
    CURRENT ERRUR
    <div class="entry">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione dolorem eos et totam doloribus ipsa illo porro unde, asperiores consequatur tempore dolor, veritatis quod corporis enim nesciunt. Corrupti est fuga nisi commodi, repudiandae harum tempore
      officia enim repellat deserunt. Nemo id animi libero molestiae vitae mollitia sequi Impedit error atque veniam tempore ea facilis qui voluptates natus voluptatibus. Illo vitae consequatur explicabo.cxzczxczx dsadsxxa..
      <div class="read-more">
        Read more
      </div>
    </div>
    This is how I want it to look like.
    <div class="entry">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione dolorem eos et totam doloribus ipsa illo porro unde, asperiores consequatur tempore dolor, veritatis quod corporis enim nesciunt. Corrupti est fuga nisi commodi, repudiandae harum tempore
      officia enim repellat deserunt. Nemo id animi libero molestiae vitae mollitia sequi Impedit error atque veniam tempore ea facilis qui voluptates natus voluptatibus. Illo vitae consequatur explicabo.cxzczxczx dsadsxxa..
      <div class="read-more no-float">
        Read more
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but I want it to float on the right when there is enough space.